# phpmyadmin configuration on zend server community edition

Tags: phpmyadmin, zend-server-ce

hi i am new to zend and i installed zend server in my local machine, i found phpmyadmin on my instalation directory and i copied it on htdocs.
while running http://localhost/phpmyadmin it appears login page and when i enter username and password it does not redirects to the main page.
instead it gives "internal server error"
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the lastest version from zend website then You should try reinstalling your Zend Server CE, The correct phpmyadmin url is http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/ over windows machine otherwise you would get page not found.

Be sure that you don't have another apache instances running also in services panel.

Answer (score 3):

Acturely, Zend Server 6 doesn't contain phpmyadmin anymore. You need install it as web app by yourself. http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-6/content/installing_phpmyadmin.htm